# "static_cast<To>(from)" if and only if "To to{from}", or not?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, static-cast

Yesterday in the course of answering someone else's question I was
surprised to discover that gcc 4.7.2 `<type_traits>` contained the trait
template `std::is_explicitly_convertible<From,To>`, defined
as the inverse of `std::is_constructible_convertible<To,From>`:

```
/// is_explicitly_convertible
template<typename _From, typename _To>
struct is_explicitly_convertible
: public is_constructible<_To, _From>
{ };
```

Searching for paper-trail, I then discovered that this trait ought not to have
been there. A [bug](http://gcc.1065356.n5.nabble.com/Bug-libstdc-55053-New-std-is-explicitly-convertible-should-be-removed-td881522.html)
was raised against its inclusion in that version of the
C++11 Standard Library and it was removed in gcc 4.8.0.

That bug report pointed out that `std::is_explicitly_convertible` (having
been mandated in earlier drafts of the C++0x Standard), was removed from the
draft Standard by [N3047](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3047.html)
in 2010.

N3047 explains this about-turn:

> The remaining question is, in which way the also affected `is_explicitly_convertible` trait should be repaired. The basic choices are:
>
> 1. Fix `is_explicitly_convertible` by returning to the current `static_cast` expression, no longer making `is_explicitly_convertible` dependent on `is_constructible`.
> 2. Remove `is_explicitly_convertible` from the standard.
>
> The first choice was considered, but it turned out that there exist quite different understandings of what "explicitly convertible" should actually mean. While some believe that `static_cast` correctly expresses this, others believed that the fixed `is_constructible` would provide a better meaning for `is_explicitly_convertible` as well. Therefore this paper recommends to remove the `is_explicitly_convertible` from the working draft. This should do no harm now, because nothing depends on that special definition yet. And if it turns out, that the trait would still be useful, it could be added in another revision of the standard.

This explanation seems to imply that the parties to the disagreement knew of
cases in which, for an expression `from` of type `From`, `static_cast<To>(from)` would
compile while `To to{from};` would not; or vice versa.

Are there such cases?

If not, can anyone authoritatively (not speculatively, please) explain
the distinction between static_castibility of `From` to `To` and
constructibility of `To` from `From` that was in play here?

Comment: Do *not* use `T to{from}` in generic code - it can yield vastly different results to `T to(from);`.

Comment: Can you point me somewhere that illustrates this?

Comment: Think `std::vector<size_t>` for example - `T to{10}` will yield a single-element vector, while `T t(10)` will yield a 10 element vector.

Comment: Right, so "uniform initialization" isn't.

Comment: @MikeKinghan: Absolutely it isn't. Uniform init and UTF-8 literals are one of those features where we were better off without. Embarrassing that those two passed Committee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, some test code.  `TestA` is your explicit construction, and `TestB` is your explicit `static_cast`ing:

```
template<typename To, typename From>
To TestA(From from) {
  To to{from};
  return to;
}
template<typename To, typename From>
To TestB(From from) {
  return static_cast<To>(from);
}
```

`static_cast` allows downcasting in an object heirarchy, while explicit construction does not:

```
struct Base {};
struct Derived:Base {};

int main() {
  Base* b;
  // TestA<Derived*>(b); -- fails to compile
  TestB<Derived*>(b);
}
```